# Дженерик метод с классами интерфейса

Tags: c#, unity3d, интерфейс, generics

Пилю игру на Unity.
Решил описать несколько почти одинаковых классов через интерфейсы.

Идея:
Есть компоненты `HealthComponent` и `ManaComponent` наследуемые от интерфейса `IIndicatorComponent`. Необходимо реализовать отображение их переменных через классы `HpBar` и `MpBar` наследуемых от `IIndicatorBar`.

Реализация:

```
public interface IIndicatorBar
{
     public void Initialize<T>(T component) where T : IIndicatorComponent;
     ...
}

public class HpBar : MonoBehaviour, IIndicatorBar
{
    [SerializeField] private HealthComponent _healthComponent;

    public void Initialize<T>(T healthComponent) where T : HealthComponent
    {
        _healthComponent = healthComponent;                                        
        Refresh();
    }
...
}
```

Проблема:
Метод `Initialize` выдаёт ошибку **CS0425** мол ограничения метода отличаются от того что описано в интерфейсе, однако в этом классе мне нужен конкретно `HealthComponent`, который является дочерним тому что указан в интерфейсе.В классе *MpBar* ситуация аналогична. Если заменить класс на тот что в интерфейсе, то переменная `_healthComponent` будет жаловаться на несоответствие классов.

Вопрос:
Что нужно сделать, чтобы можно было корректно присваивать переменным `_healthComponent` и  `_manaComponent` из другого класса их входные данные?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public interface IFoo<T> 
{
    void DoSome(T arg);
}
```

```
public class FooStr : IFoo<string>
{
    public void DoSome(string arg) { }
}

public class FooInt : IFoo<int>
{
    public void DoSome(int arg) { }
}
```

Но экземпляры классов реализующие `IFoo<string>` и `IFoo<int>` это представители двух разных классов не имеющих общего потомка/интерфейса.

---

У тебя в корне не верный DI. Чем вообще отличаются `HpBar`, `MpBar`, `StaminaBar`, `BreathBar` и т.д... ? НИЧЕМ! Вся суть бара это брать значение и максимальное значение, меняя слайдер, как бы он не выглядил, это должен быть один класс и интерфейс ему не нужен! Нужен только интерфейс для взятия значений!

```
public class Bar : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Slider _slider;
    [SerializeField] private Text _values;
    private IFloatingProperty _property;

    private void OnEnable ()
    {
        if (_property != null)
        {
            _property.Changed += UpdateValue;
            UpdateValue();
        }
    }

    private void OnDisable () 
    { 
        if (_property != null)
            _property.Changed -= UpdateValue;
    }
    
    public void SetProperty (IFloatingProperty property)
    {
        OnDisable();
        _property = property;
        OnEnable();
    }

    private void UpdateValue ()
    {
        if (_slider != null)
            _slider.value = _property.Value / _property.Max;
        if (_values != null)
            _values.text = string.Format("{0} / {1}", _property.Value, _property.Max);
    }
}
```

```
public interface IFloatingProperty
{
    event Action Changed; // по желанию можно сделать отрисовку событийной

    float Value { get; }
    float Max { get; }
}
```

Само хп и остальное, может быть чем угодно, сущностью принимающую статы для максимального значения и регена, которая должна реализовывать интерфейс. Или просто значением в каком-нибудь справочнике типа `Unit.Propertys` и тогда интерфейс реализует адаптер берущий значения по ключам, которые ему указали.

Comment: Спасибо за советы. Я лишь недавно начал использовать дженерики и ваше решение по ним помогло. Касаемо общего класса для всех баров - кажется я понял к чему вы клоните и попробую поступить именно так.